# JSON object returned as file download (Spring MVC)

Tags: json

Instead of loading my JSP, the JSON object is returned as file download. Here's my Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newProduct", method=RequestMethod.GET)public @ResponseBody ProductDetails getNewProductForm(@RequestParam String categoryName) {
```

ProductDetails product = new ProductDetails();
 product.setCategoryName(categoryName);
 return product;}

And when i open the file to download, this is what is open as text file.

```
{"price":null,"productCode":null,"categoryName":"electronics","name":null,"id":null,"description":null}
```

Could there be something wrong with my JSON jsp file? or is JSON not well configured on servlet-config. The method getNewProductForm was called from URI hyper link. Does JSON return the product object using the same URI?

Answer (score 0):

You have to let jQuery know to expect a JSON response back from the server, i.e. use the `$getJSON` function for a GET, or something like this for a POST:

```
$.post(url, $("#myForm").serialize(),
  function(data) {
    alert('data');
}, "json");
```

Comment: So my understanding is that the server has done what it should be doing. And the front-end js code should decide how to handle the json data in the file.